# ¿Cómo copiar y pegar una hoja de un archivo Excel a otro archivo Excel en construcción?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, excel

**Trasfondo**

Estoy desarrollando una funcionalidad que permite la creación de un archivo Excel, el cual debe construirse con un cierto número de hojas.

El archivo Excel a construir se compone de 5 hojas, de las cuales 3 deben ser creadas a partir de otro archivo Excel.

Para efectos de comprensión de esta pregunta, he nombrado a los archivos de esta manera:

- **Nuevo Archivo.xlsx**: *Archivo Excel a armar.*
- **Plantilla.xlsx**: *Archivo Excel que contiene las hojas que se usarán para agregar al archivo (**Nuevo Archivo.xlsx**)*

Adjunto los enlaces de los archivos [Plantilla.xlsx](https://mega.nz/#!mdxQ2BjK!SMorEA1sB2JfqZ1ifURrmySifDSJZSJUoOz2SDx90xE) y [Nuevo Archivo.xlsx](https://mega.nz/#!CYIBXa7B!07IKbCYUasIgxnSsqvzcTp0-v8nF3tFABR8fCD8VrVI) en caso de que deseen revisar su contenido.

Del archivo **Plantilla.xlsx** solo se usarán estas hojas:

- H3 Custom
- VENTAS
- DATOS

---

**Implementación**

Luego de buscar cómo puedo copiar y pegar otra una hoja de Excel a otro archivo Excel, encontré esta [respuesta](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/697233/How-to-copy-data-from-one-excel-sheet-to-another#answer2), la cual provee un código fuente que he modificado para mis propósitos:

```
#region INTENTO #3.1

// Fuente: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/695539/How-to-copy-data-from-one-excel-sheet-to-another
bool hasErrors = false;

try
{
    string ruta_plantilla = @"C:\Plantilla.xlsx";
    string ruta_archivo_final = @"C:\Nuevo Archivo.xlsx";

    // Instancia de Excel.
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel
        = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

    // Abrir el excel-plantilla:
    Workbook wbSource = excel.Workbooks.Open(ruta_plantilla, 0, false, 1, "", "", false,
                                             XlPlatform.xlWindows, 9, true, false, 0, true, false, false);

    // Abrir el archivo donde se guardará todos los datos.
    Workbook wbDestination = excel.Workbooks.Open(ruta_archivo_final, 0, false, 1, "", "", false,
                                                  XlPlatform.xlWindows, 9, true, false, 0, true, false, false);

    // Detectar cuántas hojas tiene.
    int cantHojas = wbDestination.Sheets.Count;

    // Si son menores a 5...
    if (cantHojas < 5)
    {
        // Agregar las hojas faltantes.
        Sheets hojas = null;
        Worksheet wrkSh = null;
        for (int i = cantHojas; i < 5; i++)
        {
            hojas = wbDestination.Sheets;
            wrkSh = hojas.Add(Type.Missing, wbDestination.Worksheets[i], Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            releaseObject(hojas);
        }
    }

    // Obtener la plantilla de la hoja #3.
    Worksheet wkrSh_src_pl3 = wbSource.Sheets[3];
    wkrSh_src_pl3.UsedRange.Copy(Type.Missing);
    // Copiar en estas hojas.
    // Copiarla en la hoja #4 del archivo final.
    Worksheet wrkSh_pl3 = wbDestination.Sheets[3]; // Hoja que contiene la plantilla.
    wrkSh_pl3.UsedRange.PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteAll, XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    wrkSh_pl3.Name = wkrSh_src_pl3.Name;
    wrkSh_pl3.Columns.AutoFit();


    // Obtener la plantilla de la hoja #4.
    Worksheet wkrSh_src_pl4 = wbSource.Sheets[4];
    wkrSh_src_pl4.UsedRange.Copy(Type.Missing);
    // Copiarla en la hoja #4 del archivo final.
    Worksheet wrkSh_pl4 = wbDestination.Sheets[4]; // Hoja que contiene la plantilla.
    wrkSh_pl4.UsedRange.PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteAll, XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    wrkSh_pl4.Name = wkrSh_src_pl4.Name;
    wrkSh_pl4.Columns.AutoFit();


    // Obtener la plantilla de la hoja #5.
    Worksheet wkrSh_src_pl5 = wbSource.Sheets[5];
    wkrSh_src_pl5.UsedRange.Copy(Type.Missing);
    // Copiarla en la hoja #5 del archivo final.
    Worksheet wrkSh_pl5 = wbDestination.Sheets[5]; // Hoja que contiene la plantilla.
    wrkSh_pl5.UsedRange.PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteAll, XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    wrkSh_pl5.Name = wkrSh_src_pl5.Name;
    wrkSh_pl5.Columns.AutoFit();

    // Establecer la primera hoja como "activa".
    wbDestination.Sheets[1].Activate();

    wbDestination.Save();
    wbSource.Close();
    excel.Quit();
    hasErrors = false;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + SALTO_DE_LINEA + ex.Message, TITULO, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    RegistrarEventosDelPrograma(DateTime.Now, "Error al copiar hoja a otro excel: " + ex.ToString());
    hasErrors = true;
}

#endregion
```

El **problema** con este código es que, al copiar la hoja 3 *llamada **VENTAS*** no la pega igual a como se muestra en la plantilla.

*La captura de pantalla #1* muestra la hoja ***VENTAS*** contenida en el archivo **Plantilla.xlsx**:

[image: Captura 1: VENTAS]

*La captura de pantalla #2* muestra la hoja ***VENTAS*** generada con el código anterior en el archivo **Nuevo Archivo.xlsx**:

[image: Captura 2: VENTAS-resultado]

Las demás hojas *es decir **H3 Custom** yy **DATOS*** se generan correctamente en el archivo nuevo de Excel; pero no es el caso de la hoja **VENTAS**.

Mis preguntas son:

- **¿Cómo copiar y pegar una hoja de un archivo Excel a otro archivo Excel en construcción?**
- ¿Qué otra manera puedo emplear para *por programación* copiar y pegar una hoja de Excel a otro archivo Excel?

Comment: Veo que los números se extraen de otro archivo llamado `RESUMEN DIARIO CAJA  F116.xlsx`

Comment: @ArtEze, si, este archivo lo he modificado; como tal, las fórmulas y lo demás lo debe ajustar el cliente (el proveedor de la plantilla). Mi parte del desarrollo es generar el Excel que debe contener las hojas iguales.

Answer (score 3):

Se puede hacer algo como esto en **batch**, el archivo se llamaría `procesar.bat`.

```
@echo off
@cd "C:\Archivos Excel"
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "C:\Plantilla.xlsx" -o"Ruta1"
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "C:\Nuevo Archivo.xlsx" -o"Ruta2"
del "Ruta2\xl\calcChain.xml"
del "Ruta2\xl\sharedStrings.xml"
copy "Ruta1\xl\calcChain.xml" "Ruta2\xl\calcChain.xml"
copy "Ruta1\xl\sharedStrings.xml" "Ruta2\xl\sharedStrings.xml"
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -t"zip" "Ruta1"
rename Ruta1.zip  Resultado.xlsx
```

Comment: _Se que no lo mencioné en la pregunta_, pero la ruta puede variar _se configura por aparte_; no lo mencioné porque no lo ví relevante para la generación del archivo. En todo caso, +1 y de nuevo gracias :) _dirás que soy un cabeza dura, pero entre menos modificaciones/extensiones tenga que hacer (yo o el usuario final)_ mejor.